# FTPlib error in retrbinary

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib

I get error in Line **"ftp.retrbinary("RETR" + filename, localfile.write)"**. It doesn't say what wrong exactly I just get **ftplib.error_perm:500 unknown command**. Could somoen help me to figure out this problem?

```
from ftplib import FTP

def grabfile ():

    if not os.path.exists(dtt):
        os.makedirs(dtt)


    ftp = FTP('IP')
    ftp.login(user="ftpread", passwd = 'PSW')
    ftp.cwd("/var/log/")
    filename = "scxmlsoap.log"
    #localfilename = "scxmlsoap.log"
    localfile = open(filename, "wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR" + filename, localfile.write)
    ftp.quit()
    localfile.close()
    f.close()

def main():
    grabfile()

main()
```

Comment: it says error_perm. Could it be a permission error, meaning you don't have the right permission to write the file you are trying to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space after RETR, here is an updated version.

```
ftp = FTP('IP')
ftp.login(user="ftpread", passwd = 'PSW')
ftp.cwd("/var/log/")
filename = "scxmlsoap.log"
#localfilename = "scxmlsoap.log"
localfile = open(filename, "wb")
ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % filename, localfile.write) # <-- a space added
ftp.quit()
localfile.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have no space between `'RETR'` and the filename means you're sending a single command: `'RETRscxmlsoap.log'`. This, of course, isn't interpreted as the `'RERT'` command you need.

Just add a space between them: `'RERT {}'.format(filename)`.